# Chrome Canary removes e.originalEvent.touches?

Tags: google-chrome, touch-event

Does anyone know if Chrome Canary has removed e.originalEvent.touches?
Running the following script in Chrome Stable returns 1, and in Chrome Canary returns an error (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined).

```
jQuery(document).on('touchstart', function(e){ console.log(e.originalEvent.touches.length); });
```

I'm on version 29.0.1537.0 canary on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's a browser bug. Ticketed here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=249494